# How to invoke this Objective-C Class Method in Swift 3.0？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I wanted to invoke a OC Class Method with an block in Swift 3.0：

```
@interface API : NSObject

+ (void)GetCommissionInfoWithModel:(CommissionInfoRequestModel*)model returnInfo:(void (^)(CommissionInfoResponseModel*resModel))callBackBlock；
```

I tried to invoke it like:

```
API.GetCommissionInfoWithModel(CommissionInfoRequestModel...
```

but I don't know how to continue. I know how to invoke a simple method like：

```
API.test()
API.test(para1:"1",para2:"2")
```

## but with a block, it makes me confused.

I have tried：

let someModel: CommissionInfoRequestModel = CommissionInfoRequestModel.model()

but I got another error：

> model（）is unavailable : use object construction ‘BaseModel()

Yes the `CommissionInfoRequestModel` is inherited from "BaseModel", but why I can't use  CommissionInfoRequestModel()?

Than I got an error below:

```
 Cannot convert value of type '(CommissionInfoResponseModel) -> ()' to expected argument type '((CommissionInfoResponseModel?) -> Void)!'
```

when I used the code like:

```
 API.GetCommissionInfoWithModel(someModel1){
            (resModel: CommissionInfoResponseModel) in
            // Response available in 'resModel' parameter...
        }
```

Comment: Try simply `let someModel = CommissionInfoRequestModel()`. That expression creates the object *and* callss the init/constructor method.

Comment: thank you, it works. but than another error has show up : `/Users/bijan/Desktop/灵性岛/灵性岛（代码）/LXD_Official/lxd/Class/MyCenter/ViewController/TeacherKickBackVC.swift:54:51: Cannot convert value of type '(CommissionInfoResponseModel) -> ()' to expected argument type '((CommissionInfoResponseModel?) -> Void)!'` when i used your version1 code

Comment: Try now again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let someModel: CommissionInfoRequestModel = ...
API.GetCommissionInfoWithModel(someModel) { 
    resModel in
    // Response available in 'resModel' parameter...
}
```

which is just *syntax sugar* for this longer form:

```
API.GetCommissionInfoWithModel(someModel, returnInfo: {
    (resModel: CommissionInfoResponseModel?) in
    ...
})
```

In both versions, the last argument is a *closure*:

> *Closures* are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to *blocks* in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.

For more info, please see [The Swift Programming Language book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Comment: thankyou，but i have got some error below . i can't write them all in comment so i just edite the question